# slicing a list based on values

Tags: python, list

I have a sorted list (without duplicates) in python, like so,

```
l = [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17]
```

I would like a take a slice of this based on the list values. So if the value of interest is say, 5. Then I want to locate this value in the list and get 3 values before it in the list.

I can get to my objective with the following function

```
def f(k):
    if k in l:
        i = l.index(k)
        return (l[i-2:i+1])
    else:
        pass


print (f(5))

[1, 3, 5]


print (f(13))

[9, 11, 13]
```

However, I have two problems. I do not know what I should do if the value of interest is not a list member. f(6) should also return [1,3,5]. I don't know how to locate 6 in this list

Is there some 'pythonic' way to do this

Comment: What if there are duplicates?

Comment: not having duplicates is guaranteed by the algo generating the list

Comment: f(6) should returns whole list?

Comment: `f(6) should also return [1,3,5]. I don't know how to locate 6 in this list`? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @levi... f(6) should return [1,3,5]

Comment: @nitin so what should `7` return?

Comment: @nitin you also say *get 3 values before it in the list* - but you're only get two *before* it and itself... which is correct?

Comment: @nitin also - what would `0` return or `1` return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll take a stab that since the list is sorted, and without duplicates, then you're supposed to be using some form of binary search. Python conveniently has a `bisect` module as part of the standard library.

**Code**:

```
import bisect

data = [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17]
for val in range(19):
    pos = bisect.bisect_right(data, val)
    print val, '->', data[max(0, pos-3):pos]
```

**Output**:

```
0 -> []
1 -> [1]
2 -> [1]
3 -> [1, 3]
4 -> [1, 3]
5 -> [1, 3, 5]
6 -> [3, 5, 6]
7 -> [3, 5, 6]
8 -> [5, 6, 8]
9 -> [6, 8, 9]
10 -> [6, 8, 9]
11 -> [8, 9, 11]
12 -> [8, 9, 11]
13 -> [9, 11, 13]
14 -> [9, 11, 13]
15 -> [9, 11, 13]
16 -> [9, 11, 13]
17 -> [11, 13, 17]
18 -> [11, 13, 17]
```

Comment: Why `pos-3` (I know it's very late to ask, but still)?

Comment: @scrutari `bisect_right` returns the index following the value you're after (ie - at what index you'd insert it to put that item in sorted sequence). The OP wanted to *get 3 values before it in the list.* hence the `pos-3`... However, to cater for `pos-3` being negative (and doing negative slicing), you also take the max of it and 0 so you enforce slicing from the start... Otherwise all values from 0-4 above will be empty lists.

Answer (score 6):

you can use:

```
 less_values = [x for x in l if x < 5]
```

this should you give an new list with all values smaller than 5

and there you can easily select the last 3 values

Answer (score 1):

Python's array slice notation:

```
array[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
```

So

```
array[:5] would be what you needed
```

So what you could do is:

```
v = 5
l = [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17]
if v in l:
  # do stuff
  print l[:l.index(v)]
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 3]
```

For the guy who negged this:

```
v = 6
l = [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 13, 17]
if v in l:
  # do stuff
  print l[:l.index(v)]
else:
  print "value is not in the list"
```

Outputs nothing, but that isn't a problem. I just didn't handle the exception with the appropriate else statement.

Comment: From the example in the problem statement, `f(6) == [1, 3, 5]`. Your code prints nothing.

Comment: Try it before you neg :P

Comment: `l` does not include a `6` in the problem statement. Presumably `f(7)` should also be `1, 3, 5`, and it should be that without changing `l`.

Comment: Or atleast the most recent edit of the question doesn't include a 6.

Comment: That is fine. It's not a critical issue. I amended the list to remove the '6' and stuck in an else condition to just print out the 'value is not found in the list'

Answer (score -2):

You can use index to make the search like this:

```
l.index(5)
```

Comment: yes... but this does not work for a value that is not in the list.. for example l.index(6)